# One too many commas being printed in my array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have just made a program that will take user inputs and build an array and then reverse the array. The only problem is that I need it to print the values separated by commas (,) whenever I add it to my loop it prints one too many, below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

void reverseArray(int [], int);
void printArray(int [], int );

void printArray(int arr[], int count)
{       
        cout << "{"; 
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                cout << arr[i] << ','; // here is where it is printing one two many commas.
        cout << "}" << '\n';
}

void reverseArray(int arr[], int count)
{

    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i)
     {
            temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[count-i-1];
            arr[count-i-1] = temp;
     }
}

int main ()
{
        int SIZE;
        cout << "How big is this thing " << endl;
        cin >> SIZE;
        int arr[SIZE];
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter element "<<i+1<<":";
            cin>>arr[i];
        }

        cout<<"\nBefore reverse\n";
        printArray(arr, SIZE);
        reverseArray(arr, SIZE);
        cout<<"\nAfter reverse\n";
        printArray(arr, SIZE);

        return 0;
}
```

The program runs like this

```
How big is this thing 
4
Enter element 1:3
Enter element 2:5
Enter element 3:7
Enter element 4:2

Before reverse
{3,5,7,2,}

After reverse
{2,7,5,3,}
```

How do I stop the comma printing one too many times.

Cheers.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't print one too many commas.

Comment: Try to debug properly, before posting a question here....

Comment: You print one comma after each element. If you don't want that for the last element, you have to treat that one differently.

Comment: @RawN sorry, It prints one too many commas for my situation.

Comment: @Rupsingh I have tried a few different ways, I just went back to how I had initially to try and make it easier to follow :)

Comment: Get used to the idea that programs do what you tell them to do, not what you mean them to do. Tough, I know... and it doesn't get easier. You sure you want to live the life of a programmer? If so, this question is an exercise you'd better solve it by yourself.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi alrighty i'll stick at it.

Comment: @sanchez1 Ever hear of the `if` statement?  That is what you use in the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did try that before, what I had was if (count != i) {cout << arr[i] << ",";} then I had an else statement which would cout the same thing minus the comma. But It still didn't work, any ideas.

Comment: @sanchez -- The other issue with your code is that it uses invalid C++ syntax here: `arr[SIZE]` -- In C++, you cannot declare arrays using a variable as the number of items.

Answer (score 2):

Write code as follows

```
void printArray(int arr[], int count) {       
    cout << '{'; 

    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < count-1; ++i) {
        cout << arr[i] << ',';
    } 

    cout << arr[i] << "}\n";
}
```

Comment: What if there is only one element in the array?

Comment: @RawN that defeats the purpose of the program

Comment: @RawN In that case it won't enter the loop and print the result as expected.  The problem is when there's no element in the array, then it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @sanchez1 No, when I call a function that print an array, I expect the function to work no matter how many element it's in it.

Comment: if there is only one element in the array, it works as it will not go in for loop

Comment: @RawN none the less, zero will *not* print what I (and you, apparently) expect, i.e. `{}`. Rather, it will invoke *undefined behavior*, which is *never* good.

Answer (score 2):

Is the `if` statement suddenly off-limits?  Just use it:

```
void printArray(int arr[], int count)
{       
    cout << "{"; 
    if ( count > 0 )
       cout << arr[0];   
    for(int i = 1; i < count; ++i)
       cout << ',' << arr[i];
    cout << "}" << '\n';
}
```

---

I need to mention that the other issue with your code is that you are using C++ syntax that is not valid ANSI C++ here:

```
    cin >> SIZE;
    int arr[SIZE];
```

You cannot declare arrays in C++ using a variable as the number of elements.  Your current code is using a compiler extension called `Variable Length Arrays (VLA)`.

My suggestion is to stay far away from using VLA's in a C++ program.  They cause a lot of issues, one being that they are not standard (your code will not compile with any version of the Visual Studio compiler), and the other being that a lot of runtime mistakes can be avoided by simply not using them.

Instead, use `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` is the standard C++ way to declare a dynamic array.  In addition, you have all the benefits of a `vector` knowing its size, and optional bounds checking by using `vector::at()`.  A VLA has none of these advantages.

```
   #include <vector>

    cin >> SIZE;
    std::vector<int> arr(SIZE);
```

Once you do that, then the functions you're calling no longer need the `SIZE` value passed, since a `std::vector` knows its size by simply calling the `vector::size()` member function.

Comment: @WhozCraig What do you mean by `outside the loop`?

Comment: @RawN *That* is what I meant.